# не заносятся данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Ребята помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему!

Делаю регистрацию на сайте с помощу php, ошибок не выдает никаких, но в БД данные не заносятся.
Пробовал разные варианты кода. Версия пхп на хостинге - PHP Version 5.5.26
Обновил код:

```html
<?php 

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dblogin = "u829570674_eu";
$dbpassword = "lfeu29";
$dbName = "u829570674_lf";

// Creat connection
$connect = new mysqli($dbhost, $dblogin, $dbpassword, $dbName);
// Check connection
// if($connect->connect_error){
//  die("Connect error: " . $connect->connect_error);
// }
// mysqli_select_db('users'); - не работает
$connect->select_db('users');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
 $surname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']);
 $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail']);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
 if(strlen($password) > 5){
  $password = md5($password);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, surname, email, password) VALUES ($username','$surname','$email','$password')";
  //die("INSERT INTO users ('username','surname','email','password') VALUES (".$username.",".$surname.",".$email.",".$password.")");
  echo 'Дякую за реєстрацію';
 }else{
  die ('Некорректно заповненно!  No');
 }

 if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}

?>

<form method="post" action="" id="form-register">
     <h2 class="title">Реєстрація</h2>
     <div class="id_info">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Iм'я" class="name" required>
     <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Прізвище" class="surname" required><br>
     <input type="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Ел.почта" class="email" required>
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" class="password" required><br>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-register">Зареєструватись</button> 
    </form>
```

Заранее всем спасибо

Теперь когда регистрируюсь выдает ошибку:
Р”СЏРєСѓСЋ Р·Р° СЂРµС”СЃС‚СЂР°С†С–СЋError: INSERT INTO users (username, surname, email, password) VALUES (admin','admin','eugene8686@mail.ru','d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '','admin','eugene8686@mail.ru','d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4')' at line 1
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in /home/u829570674/public_html/index.php on line 36

Comment: Тут же все в ошибке видно, admin без кавычки. VALUES ($username' У вас кавычки перед username нет

Comment: Ну и значения заносимые с использованием кавычек очень рекомендуется прогонять через mysql_real_escape_string, а то sql-инъекция элементарно делается

Comment: Дякую за реєстраціюError: INSERT INTO users (username, surname, email, password) VALUES ('admin','admin','eugene8686@mail.ru','41890cd2ac71e06b5f2c9ad5ccc07b45')
Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'

Comment: теперь такую выдает ошибку, что то с емейлом, что может быть?

Comment: ааа, там указал email, а в базе mail))

Comment: все заработало))))  Спасибо большое)